# Error in releasing gem

Tags: ruby, github, rake, release

Guys i am using jeweler to create a gem . I have successfully written my code and pushed it to      github and my git status is clean . Now when i want to release my gem i did 'rake release' 
it is creating my gem .... but its is not releasing to rubyforge . and i end up in the following error

    `Committing trisulrp.gemspec

    Pushing master to origin

    Tagging v1.2.2

Pushing v1.2.2 to origin

Generated: trisulrp.gemspec

trisulrp.gemspec is valid.

WARNING:  no rubyforge_project specified

  Successfully built RubyGem

  Name: trisulrp

  Version: 1.2.2

  File: trisulrp-1.2.2.gem

rake aborted!

Permission denied - (./trisulrp-1.2.2.gem, ./pkg/trisulrp-1.2.2.gem)`


I don kno where am goin wrong .......

Comment: Did you fix this?  I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permissions in the directory where you run the command. It complains that it can't write the `.gem` file.

Answer (score 0):

Try preceding the command with sudo:

```
sudo rake release
```